# asp.net mvc3 - calling controller actions from external app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have an asp.net mvc3 application built with RavenDB and I want to be able to access the data via an external HTML5 mobile app.  I'm thinking of exposing methods via WCF or via MVC controller action methods?  Which option is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have faced similar situation a while ago. This the way I have handled it, I have directly exposed Controller urls to the mobile application clients. Bascially it will help you in reducing the burden of maintaining two code bases and helps you to reuse existing functionality. Even if you go with WCF you need to expose with REST to make HTML5 client developer life easy.

This is the why microsoft released ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Apis to avoid confusion among developers which way to go in these scenarios. So that your services are device agnostic and easily testable.

Comment: Thanks Pavan, just read about ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Apis and it is just as you said which is it great :-)  Using ASP.NET MVC 3 all I need to do is expose action methods that return the data in JSON format that I need to consume in my app, essentially this is my service layer?

Comment: mark your choice of response as answer if it helps you. That encourages others to answer your questions in future

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already built the app in MVC3, I'd recommend a JsonResult action on an MVC Controller: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_json_data_from_controller.ashx

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy. As I will be making these calls from an IPhone/Android app then I won't run into the "same origin policy" issue because essentially I'm making get/post requests from localhost?

Comment: No, you probably will; you'll have to add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to get the device's browser stack to allow the request through.